# Completeness of continuous functions space under $L^{1}$ norm

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, complete-spaces

Prove that the space of continuous functions $C([0,1])$ is not complete under the norm
$\|\cdot\|_{L^{1}([0,1])}$.

I have tried the following sequence of functions
$f_{n}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}1 & \text { if } & 0 \leq x \leqslant \frac{1}{2} \\ 1-n\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) & \text { if } \frac{1}{2} \leqslant x \leqslant \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n} \\ 0, & \text { if } \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n} \leqslant x \leqslant 1\end{array}\right.$

I got
$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}}\left|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)\right| d x .$
$=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}}\left|\left(1-n\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)-\left(1-m\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\right| d x=\left|\frac{m-n}{2 n^{2}}\right|$

Is the last term bounded by $\frac{1}{n}$? why? and is it ok that my integration limits deals with $n$ and not also $m$?

As last step I thought of taking limit of n to $\infty$ and since 2 limits are obtained - $0,1$ this space is not complete.

Comment: Are you assuming that $m>n$? Why are you integrating from ${1 \over 2}$ to ${1 \over 2}+ {1 \over n}$?

Comment: Yes but I am not sure if it is ok

Answer (score 1):

Say $m>n$. Then

$$\int_0^1 |f_n-f_m|=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m}}|f_n-f_m|+\int_{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}} |f_n-f_m|$$

You've already dealt with the first integral on the RHS. To deal with the second one, note that
$$ \int_{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}} |f_n-f_m|=\int_{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}} |f_n|\le \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}$$
because $|f_m(x)|=0$ whenever $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m}\le x\le \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}$ and $|f_n|\le 1$ everywhere.

This shows that $\{ f_n\} _{n=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy in $(C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_1)$.

Suppose, towards a contradiction, that $f_n\to f$ in the $L^1$ norm for some $f\in C([0,1])$. Let $g$ be the characteristic function of $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$. You can check that $f_n\to g$ in the space $(L^1,\|\cdot\|_1)$, so that $f=g$ a.e. But this is impossible (do you see why?).

Comment: Thank you! what do you mean by characteristic function of  an interval? I think that what I understand is that $g$ is a.e. 1 and it's different from the value of $f$ in the interval $[0.5,1]$

Comment: Just because I'm being curious, if I'll take the following sequence  $f_{n}(x)= \begin{cases}1-n x & \text { if } 0 \leq x \leq 1 / n \\ 0 & \text { if } 1 / n<x \leq 1\end{cases}$ will it work?

Comment: @Lovemaths Given any set $A$, the characteristic function of $A$ (usually denoted $\chi_A$) is defined by $\chi_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $\chi_A(x)=0$ if $x\not\in A$. In the context of probability theory, the word "indicator" is used instead of characteristic function. And yes, the new example you suggested will work too. More generally, any sequence of continuous functions which converges in $L^1$ to a function that is not a.e. equal to a continuous function does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $m<n$, we first show $(f_n)$ is cauchy's sequence.
$\|f_n-f_m\|= \int_0^1 |f_n-f_m|dx$

RHS is equal to

$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}}|m(x-\frac{1}{2})-n(x-\frac{1}{2})|dx+$
$\int_{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m}}|1-m(x-\frac{1}{2})|$

Try to simplify, if needed you can use $\frac{n-m}{2n^2} \leq \frac{n+m}{2n^2} <\frac{n+n}{2n^2}=\frac{1}{n}$.
Once you prove it is cauchy's, you can easily show it does not coverge in given space.

Answer (score 1):

With your idea, you get a sequence $f_n$ on $[0,1]$ such that on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ it converges (in the $L^1$ norm) to a function $g$ ( constant $1$), on $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ it converges to a function $h$ ( constant $0$). Note that the $L^1$ norm on $[0,1]$ is the sum of the $L^1$ norms on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $[\frac{1}{2},1]$. So the sequence $f_n$ will be Cauchy. However, $f_n$ does not converge to a continuous function $f$. Otherwise, $f$ would equal $g$ on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, and $h$ on $[\frac{1}{2},1]$, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If $m,n \ge N$ then $f_n(x) = f_m(x)$ if $x \notin [\frac12,\frac12+{1 \over N}]$ and so $\|f_m-f_n\|_1 \le {1 \over N}$. It follows that $f_n$ is Cauchy. If we let $f=1_{[1,\frac12]}$ we see that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ pointwise. In a similar manner, it is straightforward to see that $\|f_n-f\|_1 \le {1 \over n}$.

To finish we need to show that the equivalence class $[f]$ contains no continuous function. Suppose $g \sim f$, then there are $x_n \uparrow \frac12, y_n \downarrow \frac12$ such that $g(x_n)=f(x_n) = 1$ and $g(y_n) = f(y_n) = 0$. In particular, $g$ is not continuous.